# How to change title's text style of ExpansionTile in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, accordion

I'm making an application by flutter.

I want to customize ExpansionTile Widget.
In normal, when expansion tile is expanded, its title's color turns to be blue.
Instead, I want to get it bold font.

```
return ExpansionTile(
  textColor: Colors.black,
  title: Text(_fencingClubDataList[index].Name),
  expandedAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  expandedCrossAxisAlignment:
      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
      defaultVerticalAlignment:
          TableCellVerticalAlignment.top,
      children: [
        TableRow(children: [
          Text("This is"),
          Text("a sample."),
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

I understand that you can change expanded tile's color by using textColor property.
Is there any way to change its text style like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
 bool isExpand = false;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ExpansionTile(
            onExpansionChanged: (bool isExapnd) {
              setState(() {
                isExpand = isExapnd;
              });
            },
            textColor: Colors.black,
            title: Text(
              "Title",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: isExpand ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            expandedAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Table(
                border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
                defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.top,
                children: [
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Text("This is"),
                    Text("a sample."),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool _customTileExpanded = false;
ExpansionTile(
      title: Text('ExpansionTile 2', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: _customTileExpanded ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal)),
      subtitle: const Text('Custom expansion arrow icon'),
      children: const <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 2')),
      ],
      onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
        setState(() => _customTileExpanded = expanded);
      },
    )
```

now using this bool variable `_customTileExpanded` , you can style as you want. You can find more information in here [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html)

Comment: it worked well. thank you so much. and i will check the documentation,too.